# Kubernetes fission setup error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-fission

There is an error during fission setup on minikube.
I went through this instruction: http://fission.io/docs/v0.2.1/install/ 
On this command:

```
helm install --namespace fission --set serviceType=NodePort https://github.com/fission/fission/releases/download/v0.2.1/fission-all-v0.2.1.tgz
```

There is an error:

```
Error: apiVersion "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1" in fission-all/templates/deployment.yaml is not available
```

My env is OSX Sierra 10.12.16

kubectl version is: 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was figured out that the problem was due to installation of old minikube version: v0.16.0.

After upgrade to  v0.22.1 everything works as expected